# How to play a custom sound in Electron

Tags: electron

I am using Electron 8.0.3 and I am trying to play a custom sound. Here's what I am doing:

```
  const notif = new Notification({
    title: 'Finished Download',
    body: 'test',
    sound: 'vapp/assets/sounds/mighty_sound.mp3',
  });

  notif.show();
```

It doesn't seem to play that sound but instead a default macOS sound. I've tried:

- Using a absolute path like `'/Users/<name>/Desktop/workspace/proj/vapp/assets/sounds/sound.mp3'`
- Packaging the application so that the sound is bundled
- Playing different file types: .wav, .mp3, .aiff
- Choosing other macOS sounds that might exist in `/System/Library/Sounds`

For whatever reason, it plays the same sound.

I have referenced this [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/notification#playing-sounds)

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path for the sound instead?

Comment: Yep - mentioned that in the original post

Comment: Oh my bad sorry, are you using `electron-packager` or `electron-builder`?

Comment: electron-builder but I can’t get this to work in development too

Answer (score 2):

My approach was to set the `silent` attribute of electron's Notification module to `true` so that the OS sound doesn't play and then use this `sound-play` npm package to play my own sound.

```
const showNotification = () => {
  new Notification({
    title: "Elon Musk is Tesla CEO",
    body: "The automaker just got...",
    silent: true, //// Disable sound by operating system
  }).show();

  // Play custom sound
  const sound = require("sound-play");
  sound.play("./src/quite-impressed.mp3");
};
```

Comment: Does this work in the main process, or the renderer process? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Web Notifications API, so you need to play sound in renderer process, you  can use html5 audio with base64 data instead of sound file url:

```js
import soundBase64Data from '../path/to/sound.wav'

new Notification('Notification title', {
    body: 'Notification body',
    icon: 'icon.png',
    silent: true // notification is silent - no sounds or vibrations issued
})

new Audio(soundBase64Data).play()
```